# How to write dynamically in Javascript (react project)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I had a static code that was working just fine, but when I tried to use a `map()` over a array to produce the same result dynamically, it doesn't work anymore.

I think that I made a syntax mistake when mapping my array. Can someone point out what is my mistake?

Here is the old static code that works fine:

```
const GridContent = (props)=>{
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container}>
           <ProgressBar percentage="100" styleName="ProgressBar1"></ProgressBar>
           <ProgressBar percentage="24" styleName="ProgressBar2"></ProgressBar>
           <ProgressBar percentage="48" styleName="ProgressBar3"></ProgressBar>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is what I tried to make it dynamic:

```
const fakeData3=[{percentageItem: '100'}, {percentageItem: '24'}, {percentageItem: '48'}, {percentageItem: '12'}, {percentageItem: '90'}, {percentageItem: '57'}, {percentageItem: '72'}, {percentageItem: '50'}, {percentageItem: '39'}]

const GridContent = (props)=>{
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container}>
            {fakeData3.map((item, index)=>{
                return <ProgressBar percentage={`"${item.percentageItem}"`} styleName={`"ProgressBar${index+1}"`}></ProgressBar>
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

I think there is a syntax mistake on the return of my last part of code ...

Comment: Why do you think there's a mistake?  Is something not working in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have overcomplicated your quotes here -

```
<ProgressBar percentage={`"${item.percentageItem}"`} styleName={`"ProgressBar${index+1}"`}></ProgressBar>
```

try -

```
<ProgressBar percentage={item.percentageItem} styleName={`ProgressBar${index+1}`}></ProgressBar>
```

Comment: It works perfectly !! Many thanks :) I thought I needed to display the " " to keep the same structure than when it was not dynamic. Why is it now useless ?

Comment: attributes/props in react can either be object based e.g myProp={myValue} or string based e.g. myProp="myValue", but since you need to use string template to inject some value using `${val}` you have to use the object notation along with template literal string.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing quotations. The right code should be:

```js
return <ProgressBar percentage={item.percentageItem} styleName={`ProgressBar${index+1}`} />
```

1. percentage is already a `string`, so you can use it directly as `{item.percentageItem}`
2. If you do `"something"`, styleName is actually becoming `"\"something\""` (notice the escaped ") internally.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the redoundant double quotes:

```
{fakeData3.map((item, index) => (
    <ProgressBar percentage={item.percentageItem} styleName={`ProgressBar${index+1}`} />
))}
```

Comment: the OP has `return` which does the same job within `{}`

Comment: @andymccullough Oh yes you are right, that is not the problem here then. It is most likely due to the double quotes then